# How to get Year/Week according to ISO?

Tags: sql, oracle, iso

I have the below code, which gives week 202153. However, I would need to have, instead of the first week of year 2021 as 202153, as 202053.

Is there any built-in functionality to address this?

```
SELECT
    to_char(TO_DATE('20210104', 'YYYYMMDD') - 3, 'YYYYIW') AS yearweek
FROM
    dual
```

Expected output: 202053. I could simply decode the value, but I'm hoping for a more robust solution for future years.

Comment: Maybe use the official format according to ISO-8601: `TO_CHAR(..., 'IYYY"W"IW')` in order to avoid ambiguous format `YYYYMM`

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by ambiguous?

Comment: According to ISO-8601 `202112` means "December 2021". Official format for Week 12 in 2021 is `2021-W12` or `2021W12`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IYYY` (ISO-year) rather than the `YYYY` (calendar year) format model.

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR( DATE '2021-01-04' - 3, 'IYYYIW') AS yearweek
FROM   DUAL
```

Which outputs:

> | YEARWEEK |
> | --- |
> | 202053 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3f5be27843f9c127b9143757738db631)*

Comment: Thanks! I've noticed that you've included DATE '2021-01-04'. Is there any way of achieving the same for '20210104' without using to_date?

Comment: @jeiv `DATE '2021-01-04'` is a date literal. `'20210104'` is a string literal and would need a cast to convert it to a date; while you could theoretically use `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYYMMDD';` and then `SELECT TO_CHAR( CAST( '20210103' AS DATE )- 3, 'IYYYIW') AS yearweek FROM DUAL` it is bad practice to rely on implicitly using format models like that. Just use `TO_DATE` to convert the strings to dates.